# Monadic way to read bits from Get monad

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I need to read some amount of bits from Get monad. Now my code looks like

```
readBits :: Int -> Int -> Get (Word32, Int)
readBits count state = ...

readValue :: Get (Word32, Word32)
readValue = do
   -- read fst bit count 
   (bits1, s0) <- readBits 5 0
   -- read bits1 bits as fst
   (fst, s1) <- readBits bits1 s0
   -- read snd bit count
   (bits2, s2) <- readBits 5 s1
   -- read bits2 bits as snd
   (snd, s3) <- readBits bits2 s2  
   -- flush incomplete byte
   when (s3 /= 0) $ skip 1
   return (fst, snd)
```

I want to wrap this into some kind of state monad, to have code like

```
readBits :: Int -> BitReader Word32
readBits count = ...

runBitReader :: BitReader a -> Get a

readValue :: Get (Word32, Word32) 
readValue = runBitReader $ do
      bits1 <- readBits 5
      fst <- readBits bits1
      bits2 <- readBits 5
      snd <- readBits bits2
      return (fst, snd)
```

What functions should I implement? How should they be implemented?

I have looked into Get and BitGet source code, but not fully understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most typical usecase for Monad Transformers.

You have defined most of the structure correctly. To answer your questions

```
What functions should I implement?
```

- Well you first need to wrap `Get` monad into the `StateT` Transformer to get `BitReader`.
- You need to implement proper definition for `readBits` using `get` to get the current state and `put` to save the state back.
- You need to run your code wrapped in `BitReader` to get back the output in `Get` Monad. So you need to define `runBitReader` using `runStateT`.

To answer your next question.

```
How should they be implemented?
```

I have given the possible implementation. You still need to define some functions to make it work.

```
import Control.Monad.State 
import qualified Control.Monad.State as ST
import Data.Binary 

type BitReader = StateT Int Get

readBits' :: Int -> Int -> Get (Word32, Int)
readBits' = undefined   

readBits :: Int -> BitReader Word32
readBits n = do 
    s0 <- ST.get 
    (a,s1) <- lift $ readBits' n s0
    ST.put s1 
    return a


runBitReader :: BitReader a -> Get a
runBitReader w = do 
    (a,s) <- runStateT w 0
    return a

readValue = do
      fst <- readBits 5
      snd <- readBits 10
      return (fst, snd)
```

I don't know how looking into code of `Get` was going to help you. You were looking in the wrong house. You need to read about `State Monads` and `Monad Transformers`.

You can read more about monad transformers [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html).